# Why are @end's not being seen by compiler?

Tags: xcode

I have 2 classes, an NSObject and an NSView. No AppDelegate.

I was getting a hard error "method definition not in @implementation context" even though the methods were between @implementation and @end. Moving a #import ahead of @implementation eliminated that but then variables from the other file were not known. To get rid of it, I wound up  // commenting out all the code lines in both .h and .m files. There's no code left except @interfaces, @implementations, and @ends.

I still get a warning "@end must appear in implementation context." One of them appears immediately after the @end!

I have not attempted to use IB in this program.

Other programs compile correctly, and I think the code is correct in his one and it should work.

Is there some way the compiler gets stuck? OSX 10.6.8, Xcode 3.2.6.

Comment: You'll have to post the complete file; you have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: The files are too long to post here. As I mentioned above, all the code has been // commented out, so the files are effectively empty. Ignoring the //'ed text, the files look brand new, and still the error message keeps coming up when I build the effectively empty project. My concern is whether I have a defective compiler or possibly even a hardware defect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on that project, created a new project, and copied and pasted the text from the bad one. The new project works fine with the same old text.
Then I ran memtest repeatedly and Applejack to clean up. The hardware is ok.

Probably the compiler is flaky; I've had to do this a couple times this year. Last time an error message said that the compiler had a partition problem; Google links said to upgrade and maybe the new version would fix the problem. So I installed Xcode 3.2.6, which produced the same error, unfortunately. Copy and paste to a new project was necessary, again.